# How to solve the issue of no address associated with hostname in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, python-3.x

I use Ubuntu virtual machine with python 3 inst talled to run the following code snippet:

```
# We can always fill in the IP address
        ipaddr = socket.gethostbyname(self.url_address)
        self.SAN = "IP.1 = %s\n" % ipaddr
        fqdn = socket.getfqdn(self.url_address)
        # If address was specified as IP address and fqdn could not find a
        # hostname for it, we don't store it. Then only the IP address will
        # be given in the SAN list
        dns_counter = 1
        if not fqdn == ipaddr:
            self.SAN += "DNS.%d = %s\n" % (dns_counter, fqdn)
            dns_counter += 1
            # If the address was given as a short host name, or if 
            # gethostname() produced a short host name, we store that
            if self.url_address != fqdn and self.url_address != ipaddr:
                self.SAN += "DNS.%d = %s\n" % (dns_counter, self.url_address)
                dns_counter += 1
            # If localhost is given explicitly as the listen address, then
            # the above adds localhost to the SAN. If nothing is given, then
            # we listen on all addresses (including localhost), and we
            # should add "localhost" as a SAN.
            if self.address == "0.0.0.0":
                self.SAN += "DNS.%d = localhost\n" % dns_counter
                dns_counter += 1
                self.SAN += "IP.2 = 127.0.0.1\n"
```

I got the following error:

```
 ipaddr = socket.gethostbyname(self.url_address)
socket.gaierror: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname
```

Comment: The code line in your error is not in your code snippet... Please fix either your code or your error message. Once that's done, please also include the actual data passed to `socket.gethostbyname()`.

Comment: @marcelm : I've updated the question